# See if any values in array exist in a column (excel)

Tags: excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have an array of 30 columns and 800 rows (Sheet 1), each cell has either text or is blank. I want to check if ANY values in this array (specificially row by row) exist in a column (Custody List Hedge):

Example:

Sheet 1:

```
 ASKF    AQA6               
 ARO3    ASKD    AQA5           
 ASKA    ARMA    ARNA    ARMB    ARBA   
 ARMV    ARN6    ARNS    ARO6    AQFS   
 ARQ4    ARMJ    ARN4    ARNJ    ARO4    ARBJ
```

Custody List Hedge:

MCH Fund Number

```
BWTZ
AEGF
AEGH
AEGJ
AEGL
AEGM
AEGP
```

I've tried count, match index, vlookups but nothing seems to really be working. I don't want to use VBA. I know this could be done with loops but there has to be a function set to do this. So far I tried this but I don't think it's working everytime, not sure why...

=INDEX('Sheet 1'!D:AE,MATCH('Custody list - Hedge'!A3,'Custody list - Hedge'!A:A,0),1)

Comment: You have to do this in a single cell, or can we add a column beside MCH Fund Number to see if each item is in the other set, then perform an operation on that column?

Comment: ideally in one cell but if it has to be in two or so that's okay. I'm essentially trying to do 40 vlookups in one formula

Answer (score 0):

For this, I put the text to search in **A1** to **F5**, and the codes to search for in **A11** to **A17**

First, we need to `FIND` the text in the string: `FIND($A$11:$A$17,A1:F1)`

Next, we need to realize we need this needs to be an array formula (else it will only check A11 and A1)
This is done by using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when we actually finish construction the formula
This results in a list that looks like `#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;#VALUE!;1`

Now we convert this into something that tells us if the text was found
The values are converted by the ISERROR into `TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;TRUE;FALSE`

Then we swap the values, so we have TRUE if found and FALSE if not, with `NOT`, which inverts everything to `FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;FALSE;TRUE`

Next we convert those to numbers we can add with `--`. This is a trick to conver TRUE into 1 and FALSE into 0. We then have `0;0;0;0;0;1`

Finally, we SUM the numbers, which will then tell us how many words in the list were found in the string you are searching

This will build a final formula that looks like this:

```
{=SUM(--(NOT(ISERROR(FIND($A$11:$A$17,A1:F1)))))}
```

(The curly brackets, `{}` will let you know you entered an array formula)

You can then test this against *0* for nothing found, and *>0* for some words found

Comment: I think this is doing the opposite of what i'm trying to do. I'm looking to search in the Custody list Hedge list for ANY of the values on Sheet 1

Comment: ah I also think the way you did it is givign me a number of how many are found. I need to see the values that are found. So for example if I find ASKF, ASKD, ARNA, ARO6 in the Custody list, I need to see ASKF, ASKD, ARO6, and ARNA as the output. That's why i think row by row is the best so i can just drag this down. So I would want to put in let's say G1 to output if ASKF or AQA6 was found in A1:A7.

Comment: do you need it output, or would highlighting do? A conditional formatting formula of `=NOT(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$A$11:$A$17,1,False)))` would allow you to set a highlight on any cell that is found in your list - note that you will have to enter the cell reference `A1` by hand, else it will fix it in position, and not allow the conditional formatting to inspect each cell.

Comment: i need an output, there are 32000 cells in total, and I wouldn't be able to go through each one to check for highlights. Even if I sorted and filtered on the columns it still would be too much. Ultimately, I'm just trying to search a column (Custody List Hedge) to see if any of the values from Sheet 1 are there on a row by row basis.

so in your example, If A1 or B1 isn't there, My output would like to be N/A, blank, or 0 (anything pretty much). If either of those two values are in the array, I would want either of them to come back in the output (doesn't matter which one) thanks for your help