# Excel Matching any value across row of cells to any value in lookup list

Tags: excel-formula, match, lookup

I think I'm trying to do the opposite of the question here:
[See if any values in array exist in a column (excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065647/see-if-any-values-in-array-exist-in-a-column-excel)

I've searched excel match, lookup any value, lookup any across multiple values, and haven't found anything, but please close this if it's a duplicate. This is my first question so I may be formatting this wrong.

I have a dataset on `Sheet1` where there are data points, and I've done lookups to create a hierarchy list. e.g.

```
Node1     Parent1     Parent2     Parent3     ....
Node2     Parent1     Parent2     Parent3     ....
Node3     Parent1     Parent2     Parent3     ....
```

Which is an organizational hierarchy with a varying number of levels between the top and bottom-level nodes.

And I have a unique list in `Sheet2` of certain parents, I'll call it `SpecialParentList`. They are exclusive; only one will ever show up in each row of parents in  `Sheet1`. However, they may show up anywhere, as `Parent1`, `Parent2`, etc. A `SpecialParent` could be in `Parent1` for `Node1` and `Parent2` for `Node2`.

What I want to do is look across the `Node1` row, and check whether each parent is in the `SpecialParentList`, then return the value of that `SpecialParent`.

I feel like there should be a short way to do this without looking up each `SpecialParent` separately, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's exactly what you need, but try this. Suppose ParentA, ParentB... are the ones you want to find and Parent1, Parent2... are just some others that you aren't interested in.

I set up some test data in cells A1:F3 of sheet 1 :-

Node1,Parent1,ParentA,Parent2

Node2,Parent1,Parent2,ParentB,Parent3,Parent4

Node3,ParentC,Parent1,Parent2,Parent3

and a list in cells A1:A3 of sheet 2 which doesn't have to be in order:-

ParentA

ParentB

ParentC

Then put the following array formula in sheet1!G1 and copy it down through cells G2 and G3

=MAX((1-ISERROR(MATCH(B1:F1,Sheet2!B$1:B$3,0)))*(COLUMN(Sheet1!B1:F1)-1))

This will give the position relative to column 2 where ParentA etc are found, i.e.

2

3

1

(if not found, it gives 0, if there is more than one match gives the last one)

Then you can index it by putting the following formula in H1 and copying it down to find the value of the Parent you were looking for:-

=IF(G1,INDEX(B1:F1,1,G1),"")

I hope this helps.